# External Script Adding in Magento Custom Module Template File

Tags: jquery, magento

I have tried to include the external script in my custom admin module view file.

below script i need to include in my custom admin view file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can I add this script directly to view file without adding this in XML file? Will this cause any issue in admin pages if I add this script directly in view file?

Please suggest me ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem.

But I would strongly suggest that you use the secure version of jQuery script (i.e. http**s**), since your backend would benefit from having it come over a secure connection.